# List sub controllers in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails app I have an AdminController in `app/controllers/admin`:

```
module Admin
  class AdminController < ApplicationController

  end
end
```

And then inside the admin folder I have various other controllers which all inherit from the AdminController, e.g.

```
module Admin
  class PermissionsController < AdminController

  end
end
```

I'm trying to list all the controllers and actions under AdminController with:

```
def list
  @controllers = AdminController.descendants
end
```

But all I get is: `Admin::PermissionsController`

I've also tried `AdminController.subclasses` but get the same.

I don't want to do `@controllers = Dir.new("#{Rails.root}/app/controllers/admin").entries` because I also want to access the `action_methods`.

Why isn't `descendants` or `subclasses` working?

In my view I want to do:

```
<% @controllers.each do |controller| %>
    <h2><%= controller %></h2>
    <ul>
      <% controller.action_methods.each do |action| %>
          <li><%= action %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
<% end %>
```

Which does list all the actions but only for the current controller and it also lists action methods from the parent controllers. I only want to list the ones for each controller.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading class descendants in rails development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29662518/loading-class-descendants-in-rails-development)

Comment: I think you'd get your answer right here http://stackoverflow.com/a/19173688/702436. The classes in rails are lazy loaded. Once you eager load them, `subclasses` should work for you.